# jQuery FadeOut() doesn't work. Click just jumps instead

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Can someone shed some light on this snippet.

I'm trying to integrate the jQuery Masonry Plugin with filtering. For some reason the FadeIn portion of the function works on all levels but the fadeOut() does not.

Here is the code:

```
    $j('#filter a').click(function(){
                  var colorClass = '.' + $j(this).attr('class');
                    //if($j('.portfolio').hasClass(colorClass){

                  if(colorClass=='.box') {
                    // show all hidden boxes
                    $j('.portfolio').children('.invis')
                      .toggleClass('invis').fadeIn('slow');
                  } else {  
                    // hide visible boxes 
                    $j('.portfolio').children().not(colorClass).not('.invis')
                      .toggleClass('invis').fadeOut('slow','linear');
                    // show hidden boxes
                    $j('.portfolio').children(colorClass+'.invis')
                      .toggleClass('invis').fadeIn('slow', 'linear');
                  }
}
```

I'm still improving at my js and jquery skill set, but any help on how to test output or fix this would be much appreciated.

Here is the HTML for the filtering

```
   <div id="filter">
<ul>
    <?php
    $taxonomy = 'portfolio-box-sets';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'hierarchical=0');
        echo '<li><a class=".fbox">All</a></li>';
        if ($terms) {
          foreach($terms as $term) {
            echo '<li><a class="'.$term->name.'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
          }
        }
    ?>  
</ul></div>
```

I've also tried specifying a width to the wrapper element but it didn't help.

Comment: It seems to work when the click function remains inside of the else statement, but anytime ALL boxes are showing then it goes to hide the unchosen boxes it doesn't work. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you should post some part the html code. Why do you need an 'invis' class? Couldn't you check about hidden status?

Comment: I've added the HTML that links to the click function. Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure how that php/html code is related to the js one, not `.portfolio` nor `.box` are there. Besides that, '.fbox' is not a valid css class name, and, in the js code, you should use 'addClass()' and 'removeClass()', instead of 'toggleClass()' because you already know is the class is present or not.

Comment: For some reason when I use Chrome Developer Bar the fadeout is more prominent, I just don't know why it only lags in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a quick example of a working fadeIn fadeOut toggle loosely based off the code you provided. With the html / javascript you've posted, I'm not 100% sure what end goal is, however, hopefully this will get you in the right direction with your toggle:

[jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmarc/9fLrU/)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but that just hides them and the buttons don't work at getting them back.

Comment: The example in the jsfiddle i posted works in that case, however, it may need some adaptation to work for your case.  It was not meant to be a direct copy/paste solution.  One thing i would suggest, with the current state of your code pasted in your question, change the toggleClass to addClass or removeClass where appropriate.